# how to use placeholder in command line in linux?

Tags: linux, placeholder

Suppose I want to copy a file:

```
  scp abc root@10.10.1.1:/home/user/app_abc
```

is there a way can simplfy this command ,something like :

```
  scp abc root@10.10.1.1:/home/user/app_%1
```

BTW: I don't want to write a shell for it

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant `scp ...`, right?

Comment: What would you like to go in "%1"?

Comment: it should be scp,thanks.   %1 is just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write separate script file but you can always write one liner:

```
name=abc;cp $name app_$name
```

Did you mean scp by the way? I never used cp with this notation.

Comment: Great! that's what i am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`export BOO="abc" && scp $BOO root@10.10.1:/home/user/app_$BOO`

Comment: Great! that's what i am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you can have this command in script file (copy.sh) and use it with any file name you want as an input argument. you just need to follow the instruction :

1. Create the the Bash Script File :

   $ gedit copy.sh
2. Add your code to file and save it:

   #!/bin/sh

   scp $1 root@10.10.1.1:/home/user/app_$1
3. Make file executable for any one :

   $ chmod 777 copy.sh
4. And execute it:

   $ ./copy.sh abc